# True cofinality tcf

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, cardinals

Please, [here](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/898/) on the page 6, in the definition 0.11
I wonder what happens with the definition of "tcf" when $I$ is this poset:

```
o     o
 \   /
  \ /
   o
```

This $I$ has no $<_*-$ increasing sequence, am I right?

Comment: Well. Yes. But you should never throw PCF definitions against finite posets anyway. Always think about reduced products of cardinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK. But even the infinite "V"-shaped poset has this problem, if above some element there are 2 incomparable elements, right ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: I wish to amend my previous statement. It is not correct. There is no true cofinality if there are two elements that have no common extension. In other words, there is no point in the poset which lies above *both*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. More or less.

Note that the true cofinality is always a regular cardinal and never larger than the size of the partial order.

Since arguably $0$ is excluded by the requirement of a cofinal sequence, that means that the true cofinality of a finite partial order is either $1$ if there is a maximum, or "undefined" (which might as well be $0$) otherwise.

Of course, the definition is meant to be applied to partial orders given by $\prod_{i\in I}\lambda_i/F$ where $I$ is an infinite set of infinite cardinals, usually regular, and $F$ is a filter/ideal on $I$. From that perspective finite objects have no bearing on anything, but they do make good toys on occasion.

Comment: So it cannot happen in your considerations that some element has 2 incomparable elements above some element? Why?

Comment: Because if you have functions from $I$ such that $f(i)<\lambda_i$ for all $i$, then we can take the pointwise maximum of two functions. Two functions might be incomparable, but not incompatible.

Comment: Do you mean maximum or rather supremum?

Comment: Last time I checked, defining $h(i)=\max\{f(i),g(i)\}$ is the same as defining it by $\sup\{f(i),g(i)\}$. For finite linearly ordered sets $\sup$ and $\max$ are equal.

Comment: What is the difference bewteen incomparable and incompatible? I'm a beginner, sorry!

Comment: Incomparable: neither one is larger than the other. Incompatible: there is no element larger than both.

Comment: But when I think about your comment "Last time I checked, defining " again, we have **a new** function $h(i)$, which might not exist before in that poset $I$?

Comment: First of all $I$ is not the partial order. It is the index set. Secondly, the partial order in the PCF context is *all* functions from $I$ such that $f(i)<\lambda_i$, so $h$ is indeed in the partial order. Or it is a quotient of this product by identifying two functions that agree on some large set (e.g. a cofinite subset of $I$), in which case $h$'s equivalence class is in the partial order.

Comment: Yes this is explicating. But in my original question, in the first line in that definition 0.11 $I$ **was** a partial order. What is the relationship between this poset $I$ and your index set $I$?

Comment: If I replaced it by $J$, would that make things clearer? In the standard context the partial order is the reduced product, as I wrote.